# Can we determine the sign of this product of complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, determinant

Let $$\Lambda=\prod_{n=1}^N(a_n+ib_n)\not=0$$
where $a_n,b_n$ are real. **Can we determine $\mathrm{sign}(\Lambda)$ when $\mathrm{Im}(\Lambda)=0$ and $a_n<0\;\forall n$?**

The result can depend on $N$, but not the individual $a_n$s and $b_n$s.

---

The context for this problem is that I have the matrix product $$A=BC$$ where $A$ and $C$ are square and (in general) nonsymmetric, so $$\mathrm{det}(A)=\mathrm{det}(BC)=\mathrm{det}(B)\mathrm{det}(C).$$ I know that $\mathrm{det}(B)$ is positive and real and that $\mathrm{det}(C)$ is real (since the matrix $C$ is real, its determinant can only be real). Now I write $\mathrm{det}(A)$ as the product of the (complex) eigenvalues of $A.$ Furthermore, I know that all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part.

Comment: Sure we can determine the sign. Just compute the product and look at the number you get.

Comment: @Wojowu I don't know the eigenvalues of $A$, only that they must have a negative real part.

Comment: In that case, it's impossible to deduce the sign just by knowing that and $n$. For $n=3$, the product might be positive ($\omega\cdot\omega\cdot\omega=1$) as well as negative ($\omega\cdot\overline\omega\cdot -1=-1$) ($\omega$ is a primitive thrid root of $1$).

Comment: @Wojowu I don't think that that satisfies that all real parts of the complex numbers, here (here $\omega$), should be negative? Am I mistaken?

Comment: $\omega$ has real part $-1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't know the sign. Assuming $a+b+c=abc$ we have that

$$(-1+ai)(-1+bi)(-1+ci)=ab+ac+bc-1.$$ Now, if $a=1,b=-1,c=0$ we get $-2<0$ and if $a=b=-2,c=-4/3$ we get $25/3>0.$

Comment: That was what I feared, thanks!

Comment: That's actually $a_1a_2(1+k^2)$ which is always positive. You won't find examples with two numbers, but three are enough as I illustrate in a comment above.